# Aligning Subgraphs, Ordering Nodes, and Relocating Edges in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to draw a GraphViz graph (using version `2.38.0 (20140413.2041)`), and having a lot of trouble getting it to lay out the way I want it. I've tried many different combinations of hidden edges, constraint manipulation, subgraphs (both cluster and non-cluster), etc., and nothing seems to be doing what I want.

Here's my current code:

```
digraph G {
  subgraph clustera {
    style=invis;rank=same
    A->B->C
  }

  subgraph clusterb {
    style=invis;rank=same;rankdir=LR
    D->E [constraint=false]
  }

  subgraph clusterc {
    style=invis;rank=same
    F->G [constraint=false]
  }

  C -> D
  D -> F  [constraint=false]
  E -> C

  F -> A  [constraint=false]
  F -> C  [constraint=false]
  F -> E  [constraint=false]
}
```

And here's how it renders with `dot -Tpng`:

[image: current dot graph]

(All the `F` edges have "constraint" turned off, because almost anything else distorts the graph horribly.)

What I want is:

- node `F` above node `G`
- `F` and `G` more or less centered vertically on the graph
- `F` and `G` to the right of `A` through `E`
- `A` through `E` in more or less the arrangement they're in now
- the edges from `F` to `A`, `C`, and `E`, and from `D` to `F`, following more or less straight lines (i.e. not routing around the right-hand side of the `F`/`G` group)
- as a bonus, I'd kind of like to get `A` through `C` to center properly above `D` and `E`, but that's less important

(One thing I very much *don't* want is for `F` to appear above `A`, as if it were the root of the graph.)

Here's an approximation of what I'm looking for, laid out by hand in yEd:

[image: yEd graph]

Is this doable in GraphViz?

(I should note that I'm perfectly willing to use one of the other GraphViz tools, it's just that `dot` is the only one I'm at all familiar with.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's my approach without `subgraphs` and `weigth`s, only `group`s to vertically align nodes, and `constraint=false` as well as `dir=back` to preserve layout distortion.

```
digraph G {
  // nodes without a group
  D;
  E;

  // group left side
  node[group=left];
  A -> B -> C -> D;
  C -> E [dir=back];
  D -> E [constraint=false];

  // group right side
  node[group=right];
  F -> G;

  // inter group edges
  F -> C;
  edge [constraint=false];
  D -> F;
  F -> A;
  F -> E;
}
```

The [result can be seen here](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1424002475913#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20nodes%20without%20a%20group%0A%20%20D%3B%0A%20%20E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20group%20left%20side%0A%20%20node%5Bgroup%3Dleft%5D%3B%0A%20%20A%20-%3E%20B%20-%3E%20C%20-%3E%20D%3B%0A%20%20C%20-%3E%20E%20%5Bdir%3Dback%5D%3B%0A%20%20D%20-%3E%20E%20%5Bconstraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20group%20right%20side%0A%20%20node%5Bgroup%3Dright%5D%3B%0A%20%20F%20-%3E%20G%3B%0A%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20inter%20group%20edges%0A%20%20F%20-%3E%20C%3B%0A%20%20edge%20%5Bconstraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0A%20%20D%20-%3E%20F%3B%0A%20%20F%20-%3E%20A%3B%0A%20%20F%20-%3E%20E%3B%0A%7D) and corresponds to your approximation.

Comment: nice! I didn't know `group`. Only, there is a way to swap D / E ?

Comment: @CapelliC To swap D and E, just change the order of the first mention of those nodes (swap the first two lines of the graph and mention E before D).

Comment: @marapet ... I didn't realise the effects of first mention and flow (and controlling them with dir=back and constraint = false)! Amazing to compare the diagram just toggling those two line s  "C -> E [dir=back];" and "D -> E [constraint=false]" to "E->C;"! and "D-> E"!

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting your requirement with a little freedom you may have a graph without edges crossing

```
digraph G { rankdir = LR ranksep = 1.2 nodesep = 0.5
  { rank=same A -> B -> C -> D -> E }
  D -> F
  { rank=same F -> G }
  edge [constraint=false]
  E -> C
  F -> A
  F -> C
  F -> E
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?-->

<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.28.0 (20110507.0327)
 -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="250pt" height="332pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 250.29 332.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph1" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 328)">
<title>G</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="white" points="-4,5 -4,-328 247.294,-328 247.294,5 -4,5"></polygon>
<!-- A -->
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>A</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="75.2936" cy="-306" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="75.2936" y="-301.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">A</text>
</g>
<!-- B -->
<g id="node4" class="node"><title>B</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="75.2936" cy="-234" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="75.2936" y="-229.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">B</text>
</g>
<!-- A&#45;&gt;B -->
<g id="edge3" class="edge"><title>A-&gt;B</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M75.2936,-287.859C75.2936,-279.268 75.2936,-270.677 75.2936,-262.085"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="78.7937,-262 75.2936,-252 71.7937,-262 78.7937,-262"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- C -->
<g id="node5" class="node"><title>C</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="75.2936" cy="-162" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="75.2936" y="-157.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">C</text>
</g>
<!-- B&#45;&gt;C -->
<g id="edge4" class="edge"><title>B-&gt;C</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M75.2936,-215.859C75.2936,-207.268 75.2936,-198.677 75.2936,-190.085"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="78.7937,-190 75.2936,-180 71.7937,-190 78.7937,-190"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- D -->
<g id="node6" class="node"><title>D</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="75.2936" cy="-90" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="75.2936" y="-85.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">D</text>
</g>
<!-- C&#45;&gt;D -->
<g id="edge5" class="edge"><title>C-&gt;D</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M75.2936,-143.859C75.2936,-135.268 75.2936,-126.677 75.2936,-118.085"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="78.7937,-118 75.2936,-108 71.7937,-118 78.7937,-118"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- E -->
<g id="node7" class="node"><title>E</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="75.2936" cy="-18" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="75.2936" y="-13.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">E</text>
</g>
<!-- D&#45;&gt;E -->
<g id="edge6" class="edge"><title>D-&gt;E</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M75.2936,-71.8594C75.2936,-63.2681 75.2936,-54.6768 75.2936,-46.0854"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="78.7937,-46 75.2936,-36 71.7937,-46 78.7937,-46"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F -->
<g id="node9" class="node"><title>F</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="215.294" cy="-90" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="215.294" y="-85.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">F</text>
</g>
<!-- D&#45;&gt;F -->
<g id="edge8" class="edge"><title>D-&gt;F</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M102.575,-90C123.965,-90 154.385,-90 178.082,-90"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="178.11,-93.5001 188.11,-90 178.11,-86.5001 178.11,-93.5001"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- E&#45;&gt;C -->
<g id="edge13" class="edge"><title>E-&gt;C</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M52.7625,-28.3877C36.2645,-37.3556 15.1112,-52.027 5.2936,-72 -1.76453,-86.3591 -1.76453,-93.6409 5.2936,-108 13.4238,-124.54 29.3279,-137.445 43.9243,-146.485"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="42.3564,-149.621 52.7625,-151.612 45.8691,-143.567 42.3564,-149.621"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;A -->
<g id="edge15" class="edge"><title>F-&gt;A</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M204.475,-106.621C185.434,-138.661 141.876,-211.016 102.294,-270 99.7106,-273.849 96.9068,-277.876 94.1283,-281.785"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="91.1877,-279.879 88.1817,-290.038 96.8671,-283.971 91.1877,-279.879"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;C -->
<g id="edge17" class="edge"><title>F-&gt;C</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M193.492,-100.853C170.263,-112.973 132.471,-132.69 106.103,-146.447"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="104.2,-143.492 96.9536,-151.221 107.438,-149.698 104.2,-143.492"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;E -->
<g id="edge19" class="edge"><title>F-&gt;E</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M193.492,-79.1472C170.263,-67.0274 132.471,-47.31 106.103,-33.5528"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="107.438,-30.3018 96.9536,-28.7791 104.2,-36.5079 107.438,-30.3018"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- G -->
<g id="node12" class="node"><title>G</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="215.294" cy="-18" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="215.294" y="-13.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">G</text>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;G -->
<g id="edge11" class="edge"><title>F-&gt;G</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M215.294,-71.8594C215.294,-63.2681 215.294,-54.6768 215.294,-46.0854"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="218.794,-46 215.294,-36 211.794,-46 218.794,-46"></polygon>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

alternatively with bottom nodes on the same height

```
digraph G { rankdir = LR ranksep = 1.2 nodesep = 0.5
  { rank=same A -> B -> C -> D }
  D -> E
  B -> F [style=invis]
  { rank=same F -> G }
  edge [constraint=false]
  E -> C
  F -> A
  F:w -> C
  D -> F
  F:e -> E:e
}
```

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?-->

<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.28.0 (20110507.0327)
 -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="250pt" height="260pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 250.27 260.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph1" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 256)">
<title>G</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="white" points="-4,5 -4,-256 247.27,-256 247.27,5 -4,5"></polygon>
<!-- A -->
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>A</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="27" cy="-234" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-229.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">A</text>
</g>
<!-- B -->
<g id="node4" class="node"><title>B</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="27" cy="-162" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-157.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">B</text>
</g>
<!-- A&#45;&gt;B -->
<g id="edge3" class="edge"><title>A-&gt;B</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M27,-215.859C27,-207.268 27,-198.677 27,-190.085"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="30.5001,-190 27,-180 23.5001,-190 30.5001,-190"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- C -->
<g id="node5" class="node"><title>C</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="27" cy="-90" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-85.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">C</text>
</g>
<!-- B&#45;&gt;C -->
<g id="edge4" class="edge"><title>B-&gt;C</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M27,-143.859C27,-135.268 27,-126.677 27,-118.085"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="30.5001,-118 27,-108 23.5001,-118 30.5001,-118"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F -->
<g id="node10" class="node"><title>F</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="167" cy="-162" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="167" y="-157.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">F</text>
</g>
<!-- B&#45;&gt;F -->
<!-- D -->
<g id="node6" class="node"><title>D</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="27" cy="-18" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-13.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">D</text>
</g>
<!-- C&#45;&gt;D -->
<g id="edge5" class="edge"><title>C-&gt;D</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M27,-71.8594C27,-63.2681 27,-54.6768 27,-46.0854"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="30.5001,-46 27,-36 23.5001,-46 30.5001,-46"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- E -->
<g id="node8" class="node"><title>E</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="167" cy="-18" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="167" y="-13.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">E</text>
</g>
<!-- D&#45;&gt;E -->
<g id="edge7" class="edge"><title>D-&gt;E</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M54.2816,-18C75.6717,-18 106.092,-18 129.789,-18"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="129.816,-21.5001 139.816,-18 129.816,-14.5001 129.816,-21.5001"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- D&#45;&gt;F -->
<g id="edge20" class="edge"><title>D-&gt;F</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M42.2487,-32.8682C66.5235,-58.1984 116.031,-109.859 144.521,-139.587"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="142.176,-142.199 151.622,-146.997 147.23,-137.355 142.176,-142.199"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- E&#45;&gt;C -->
<g id="edge14" class="edge"><title>E-&gt;C</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M145.199,-28.8528C121.969,-40.9726 84.1776,-60.69 57.8095,-74.4472"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="55.9069,-71.4921 48.66,-79.2209 59.1449,-77.6982 55.9069,-71.4921"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;A -->
<g id="edge16" class="edge"><title>F-&gt;A</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M145.199,-172.853C121.969,-184.973 84.1776,-204.69 57.8095,-218.447"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="55.9069,-215.492 48.66,-223.221 59.1449,-221.698 55.9069,-215.492"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;C -->
<g id="edge18" class="edge"><title>F:w-&gt;C</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M140,-162C103.148,-162 68.7605,-134.078 48.0591,-113.01"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="50.4865,-110.483 41.0722,-105.623 45.4009,-115.293 50.4865,-110.483"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;E -->
<g id="edge22" class="edge"><title>F:e-&gt;E:e</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M194,-162C254.5,-162 257.809,-33.3193 203.926,-19.2449"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="204.358,-15.7717 194,-18 203.487,-22.7173 204.358,-15.7717"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- G -->
<g id="node13" class="node"><title>G</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="167" cy="-90" rx="27" ry="18"></ellipse>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="167" y="-85.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">G</text>
</g>
<!-- F&#45;&gt;G -->
<g id="edge12" class="edge"><title>F-&gt;G</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M167,-143.859C167,-135.268 167,-126.677 167,-118.085"></path>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="170.5,-118 167,-108 163.5,-118 170.5,-118"></polygon>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only needed one cluster to keep the ABCDE group aligned.  Backward directional arrows and weighting helped a lot.

```
digraph g
{
    subgraph cluster_subCDE {
        color=invis;
        A; B; C; D; E;
    }
    A->B [weight=10];
    A->F [dir=back];
    B->C [weight=10];
    F->C;
    C->E [color=invis];
    C->D;
    D->E [constraint=false];
    E->C;
    F->G [weight=10];
    F->D [dir=back];
    F->E;
}
```

[image]